# How to compute function field of a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, function-fields

What does $\bar{F}_q(C)$ (*function field of a curve*) mean? And, how can I compute it when I know C and $F_q$ (or $\bar{F}_q$)? (especially for q=2)

Comment: The function field is basically defined by the equation(s) of the curve. If $C$ is a plane curve, given by, say the equation $y^2+xy=x^3+1$, then the function field is $\Bbb{F}_2(x)(y)$ where $\Bbb{F}_2(x)$ is the field of rational functions of $x$, and we then extend it by adjoining $y$, a solution of the equation $y^2+xy=x^3+1$. The equation is quadratic in $y$, so $\Bbb{F}_2(x,y)$ is a degree two extension of $\Bbb{F}_2(x)$.

Comment: You need to explain how is your $C$ determined. If it is described just by the zero set of an equation  $f(x,y)=0$, the previous comment gives the answer.

Comment: @ Lahtonen: What is $F_2(x)(y)$ ? Does it mean I just add {y} to $F_2(x)$ ?

Comment: @ xarles:I suppose yes, it is represented by some polynomial $F[X, Y] \in F_q[X, Y]$. So, I must be able to compute its zero set.

 $C$ is a smooth, projective, absolutely irreducible curve defined over $F_q$.

Comment: @ Lahtonen: Sorry if my question was somehow odd. My major is computer science and I am familiar with basic definitions of algebra. If I am correct, $F_q$ is made of polynomials; so, how can I add adjoin the "point" y to "a field" to make  its extension? It seems weird to me. Must I make a polynomial which y is  its solution, and then add this polynomial to $F_q$?

Comment: y is not a point it is a variable.it just means polynomials in y with coefficient in the field.if  the elements of the field is also polynomials you get a multivariable polynomial like $(3x^2+2x+1)y^3+(2x^2+1)y=3x^2y^3+2xy^3+y^3+2x^2y+y$